# Where's my `stub-resolve.conf`?

Tags: systemd, oracle-linux

I'd like to start using `systemd-resolved` on Oracle Linux 7.6.

I'd like to use it in the mode where `/etc/resolv.conf` is just a symlink to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` having just `nameserver 127.0.0.53` as a content.

I've installed `systemd-networkd` and `systemd-resolved` packages. I've enabled the relevant services and I've disabled `NetworkManager` and `network` services.

However my installation of `systemd-resolved` doesn't contain this stub file `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`. It contains just `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`.

Could you please advise why is my `stub-resolv.conf` missing?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS many times and it's just because of the systemd-resolved.service which was either stopped automatically or deliberately.
After starting the service the file /run/systemd/resolv/stub-resolv.conf file is back.

Answer (score 1):

I'm observing the same issue on Debian 9. 
According to (man 8 systemd-resolved.service):

```
 o   A static file /usr/lib/systemd/resolv.conf is provided that lists the 127.0.0.53 DNS stub (see above) as only DNS server. This file may be symlinked from /etc/resolv.conf in order to connect all local clients that bypass local DNS APIs to systemd-resolved. This mode of operation is recommended.
```

This is not true actually the file is under:
/lib/systemd/resolv.conf
And this is a plain static file, pointing to local stub server, no search domains and etc.

If you upgrade to Debian 10 version of systemd-resolved moves from 232 to 241.
This enables the correct stub file:
/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf

I guess you are using similar systemd-resolved version as on Debian 9. Check your man and locate your resolv.conf files using find.